# including new field to views_nivo_slider

Tags: views, 6

I created a slideshow using views_nivo_slider, with two fields, one content: image, and content: description. and I want the description field to be used as a description for the image in slide, but the problem is that description field doesnt work with nivo slider, it's not changing with the image, and I only have some static description fields.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `views_nivo_slider` only accepts three values: an image, a link and a title, and therefore doesn't have anything inside it to display another field/description.

Now, if instead what you are saying is that the title isn't showing up with the image, then you need to go into Views' `Row Style: Views Nivo Slider` configuration and tell it what field you want to use for the title.  You do that by clicking on the wheel/gear widget thing to the right of that and then select from the menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jima, but what you answered wasn't specifically my question, anyway I tried views_slideshow instead.